# Importance of the --no-check-certificate option of wget

Tags: linux, download, certificate, wget

Some times `wget` will refuse to download the specified file. Adding the `--no-check-certificate`, I am often able to download the file anyway.

**1)** Briefly, what is this certificate which `wget` checks by default? How does it perform this check?

**2)** Does the need of `--no-check-certificate` for some particular URL vary from machine to machine? That is, if I'm able to download some file using `wget www.website/file`, can I be sure that my friend using some other machine can do the same, also without the `--no-check-certificate` option?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. When hitting a website that is secure (https) wget will attempt to validate the certificate. In order to trust certificates, wget would need access to a certificate store which is essentially an SSL directory to store trusted certs (see here for more info: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wget-ssl-certs)  This can be bypassed as you have seen by using the --no-check-certificate option
2. Using the --no-check-certificate option should work regardless of which machine you are using wget from.That option is specific to the wget program itself and is not machine dependent

Comment: 1) So, `wget` does not check for certs for http, ftp, etc., but only https?
2) Just to be sure: If `wget` checks for, find and accepts a cert for some particular URL, I am guaranteed that the same will happen on all other machines?

Comment: 1. Sorry, I should have clarified. Any "secure" protocol that wget can be used for. So sftp, https, etc..  2. when using --no-check-certificate, wget doesn't accept the certificate, but ignores it. that option should work from an machine that you run wget from. If you want it to accept certificates instead, then you would need to setup a certificate store, and that would need to happen on each machine indiviadually